# Pins board_s3 in Shiny app: Works locally but not remotely

Tags: r, amazon-s3, shiny, pins

I'm trying to use the pins package to access data for a Shiny app deployed on shinyapps.io. The pins board lives in an Amazon S3 bucket. Locally, everything works. But when I deploy the app, I get an "The application failed to start. exit status 1" error. The logs aren't very helpful:

```
2022-10-19T15:19:22.316043+00:00 shinyapps[6862336]: Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
2022-10-19T15:19:22.316075+00:00 shinyapps[6862336]: Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
2022-10-19T15:19:22.316080+00:00 shinyapps[6862336]: Execution halted
2022-10-19T15:19:22.316096+00:00 shinyapps[6862336]: Shiny application exiting ...
```

MWE:

```
library(pins)
board <- board_s3("vzpins",
                  region = "us-east-1",
                  access_key = Sys.getenv("S3_ACCESS_KEY"),
                  secret_access_key = Sys.getenv("S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"))

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I don't have a good theory of what's wrong -- maybe shinyapps.io is blocking the connection to S3? I tried providing the S3 keys explicitly (in case it's a problem with accessing the .Renviron file) but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I have access to shinyapps.io support, and after some back and forth we identified the issue: When deploying the app, the {{paws.storage}} package does not get included in the bundle. You have to manually include `library(paws.storage)` in the code, and then everything works!